# nodemailer always sending the same response, res.send() not working

Tags: express, nodemailer

I'm trying to send a custom response if the email sending fails or succeeds...

**server**

```js
router
    .post('/send-email', function (req, res) {

        let senderEmail = req.body.email;
        let message = req.body.message;

        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'mail.domain.com',
            port: 25,
            secure: false,
            auth: {
                user: "contact@domain.com",
                pass: "password"
            },
            tls: {
                secure: false,
                ignoreTLS: true,
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        });

        let mailOptions = {
            from: senderEmail,
            to: 'contact@domain.com',
            subject: `TITLE`,
            html: `
                ${message}
            `
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                res.send({ ok: false, message: "fail" })
            } else {
                res.send({ ok: true, message: "success" })
            }
        });

    });
```

**client**

```js
async function sendEmail(email, message) {

    let response = fetch("/send-email", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, message: message })
    })

    let result = await response;

    console.log(result)  // Always the same response
}
```

But, the server always sends the same response, regardless if the email sending failed or not...

[image]

For the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: is the function `transporter.sendMail(...)` encapsulated in a method which receives `res`?

Comment: Yes, it's inside `router.post('/send-email', function (req, res) { .... });`

Comment: Did you console log inside this function to see if it is being called at all?

Comment: Yes, I actually get the emails. Just can't send a response from the server back to the client.

Comment: Can you show us the entire request handler on the server?  I have a feeling that something you're not showing us is causing the problem like you're sending a response elsewhere in the same request handler.

Comment: @jfriend00 I expanded the server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the differing part of the response here will be in the body of the response and you have to actually read the body with `response.json()` in order to get it and see it.  See [MDN on Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for details.

All your screen shot is looking at is headers and those don't different from the two different responses you're sending.

An example that shows reading the body and parsing as JSON:

```
async function sendEmail(email, message) {

    let result = await fetch("/send-email", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, message: message })
    }).then(response -> response.json());   // read the response body and parse it as JSON

    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Note, you should also be catching errors here, either in the caller or within this function (I'm not sure which is better for your situation).